# (Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update:

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, feed

I am getting this error when I go to my feed screen, can you advise what would be? the `feedsScreen` is supposed to show me all the posts from the people I follow however it does not show anything just a blank screen and I get the error in the console.

This is the error

```
Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/flutter-instagram-clone-c2f63/databases/(default)/documents/users/euZNNwshi6C1GsDW3ONJ, null)
```

**Here is the feed screen code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/models/post_model.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/models/user_data.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/services/database_service.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/widgets/post_view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'comments_screen.dart';
import 'edit_profile_screen.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'profile_screen';
  final String currentUserId;
  final String userId;

  ProfileScreen({this.currentUserId, this.userId});

  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  bool _isFollowing = false;
  int _followerCount = 0;
  int _followingCount = 0;
  List<Post> _posts = [];
  int _displayPosts = 0; // 0 - grid, 1 - column
  User _profileUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupIsFollowing();
    _setupFollowers();
    _setupFollowing();
    _setupPosts();
    _setupProfileUser();
  }

  _setupIsFollowing() async {
    bool isFollowingUser = await DatabaseService.isFollowingUser(
      currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
      userId: widget.userId,
    );
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _isFollowing = isFollowingUser;
    });
  }

  _setupFollowers() async {
    int userFollowerCount = await DatabaseService.numFollowers(widget.userId);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _followerCount = userFollowerCount;
    });
  }

  _setupFollowing() async {
    int userFollowingCount = await DatabaseService.numFollowing(widget.userId);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _followingCount = userFollowingCount;
    });
  }

  _setupPosts() async {
    List<Post> posts = await DatabaseService.getUserPosts(widget.userId);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _posts = posts;
    });
  }

  _setupProfileUser() async {
    User profileUser = await DatabaseService.getUserWithId(widget.userId);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _profileUser = profileUser;
    });
  }

  _followOrUnfollow() {
    if (_isFollowing) {
      _unfollowUser();
    } else {
      _followUser();
    }
  }

  _unfollowUser() {
    DatabaseService.unfollowUser(
      currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
      userId: widget.userId,
    );
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _isFollowing = false;
      _followerCount--;
    });
  }

  _followUser() {
    DatabaseService.followUser(
      currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
      userId: widget.userId,
    );
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _isFollowing = true;
      _followerCount++;
    });
  }

  _displayButton(User user) {
    return user.id == Provider.of<UserData>(context).currentUserId
        ? Container(
            width: 200.0,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => EditProfileScreen(
                    user: user,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                'Editar Pefil',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontFamily: 'Varela'),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            width: 200.0,
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: _followOrUnfollow,
              color: _isFollowing ? Colors.grey[200] : Colors.blue,
              textColor: _isFollowing ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                _isFollowing ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }

  _buildProfileInfo(User user) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 0.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: user.profileImageUrl.isEmpty
                    ? AssetImage('assets/images/user.png')
                    : CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.profileImageUrl),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              _posts.length.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'posts',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              _followerCount.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'followers',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              _followingCount.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'following',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    _displayButton(user),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                user.nickname,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
              Container(
                height: 80.0,
                child: Text(
                  user.bio,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _buildToggleButtons() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on),
          iconSize: 30.0,
          color: _displayPosts == 0
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Colors.grey[300],
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            _displayPosts = 0;
          }),
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.list),
          iconSize: 30.0,
          color: _displayPosts == 1
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Colors.grey[300],
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            _displayPosts = 1;
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  _buildTilePost(Post post) {
    return GridTile(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => CommentsScreen(
              post: post,
              likeCount: post.likeCount,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Image(
          image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(post.imageUrl),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildDisplayPosts() {
    if (_displayPosts == 0) {
      // Grid
      List<GridTile> tiles = [];
      _posts.forEach(
        (post) => tiles.add(_buildTilePost(post)),
      );
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: tiles,
      );
    } else {
      // Column
      List<PostView> postViews = [];
      _posts.forEach((post) {
        postViews.add(
          PostView(
            currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
            post: post,
            author: _profileUser,
          ),
        );
      });
      return Column(children: postViews);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: usersRef.document(widget.userId).get(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          User user = User.fromDoc(snapshot.data);
          return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildProfileInfo(user),
              _buildToggleButtons(),
              Divider(),
              _buildDisplayPosts(),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**THIS IS THE POST VIEW WIDGET**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:animator/animator.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/models/post_model.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/screens/comments_screen.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:jobly10/services/database_service.dart';

class PostView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentUserId;
  final Post post;
  final User author;

  PostView({this.currentUserId, this.post, this.author});

  @override
  _PostViewState createState() => _PostViewState();
}

class _PostViewState extends State<PostView> {
  int _likeCount = 0;
  bool _isLiked = false;
  bool _heartAnim = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _likeCount = widget.post.likeCount;
    _initPostLiked();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(PostView oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.post.likeCount != widget.post.likeCount) {
      _likeCount = widget.post.likeCount;
    }
  }

  _initPostLiked() async {
    bool isLiked = await DatabaseService.didLikePost(
      currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
      post: widget.post,
    );
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isLiked = isLiked;
      });
    }
  }

  _likePost() {
    if (_isLiked) {
      // Unlike Post
      DatabaseService.unlikePost(
          currentUserId: widget.currentUserId, post: widget.post);
      setState(() {
        _isLiked = false;
        _likeCount = _likeCount - 1;
      });
    } else {
      // Like Post
      DatabaseService.likePost(
          currentUserId: widget.currentUserId, post: widget.post);
      setState(() {
        _heartAnim = true;
        _isLiked = true;
        _likeCount = _likeCount + 1;
      });
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 350), () {
        setState(() {
          _heartAnim = false;
        });
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(
                currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
                userId: widget.post.authorId,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 16.0,
              vertical: 10.0,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  backgroundImage: widget.author.profileImageUrl.isEmpty
                      ? AssetImage('assets/images/user_placeholder.jpg')
                      : CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                          widget.author.profileImageUrl),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                Text(
                  widget.author.nickname,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onDoubleTap: _likePost,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.post.imageUrl),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              _heartAnim
                  ? Animator(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      tween: Tween(begin: 0.5, end: 1.4),
                      curve: Curves.elasticOut,
                      builder: (anim) => Transform.scale(
                        scale: anim.value,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          size: 100.0,
                          color: Colors.red[400],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : SizedBox.shrink(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: _isLiked
                        ? Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )
                        : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    onPressed: _likePost,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.comment),
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => CommentsScreen(
                          post: widget.post,
                          likeCount: _likeCount,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                child: Text(
                  '${_likeCount.toString()} likes',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 4.0),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 12.0,
                      right: 6.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.author.nickname,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      widget.post.caption,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 12.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the database**

```
  static Future<List<Post>> getFeedPosts(String userId) async {
    QuerySnapshot feedSnapshot = await feedsRef
        .document(userId)
        .collection('userFeed')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Post> posts =
        feedSnapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
    return posts;
  }

This is the Post model

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Post {
  final String id;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String caption;
  final int likeCount;
  final String authorId;
  final Timestamp timestamp;

  Post({
    this.id,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.caption,
    this.likeCount,
    this.authorId,
    this.timestamp,
  });

  factory Post.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Post(
      id: doc.documentID,
      imageUrl: doc['imageUrl'],
      caption: doc['caption'],
      likeCount: doc['likeCount'],
      authorId: doc['authorId'],
      timestamp: doc['timestamp'],
    );
  }
}
```

**LOG**

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device SM A305G...
Reloaded 0 of 989 libraries in 771ms.
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (21125): token: dlwF3XAN-IU:APA91bHppNO3Ku6EzTyl_cVJnCA6Vq9lZ3CxzzBw1BJ57eN9G_bEeVtKN6YOsBzMQ0xO6C3q4FOx0YmnPW8a7DDxpRZUrWndNQwc6SNH2ek2vw_DusdBfQuxKzbkt73wF5ksTn-ssmus
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@16cc112[MainActivity](21125): ViewPostIme pointer 1
E/flutter (21125): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing updateData, NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/flutter-instagram-clone-c2f63/databases/(default)/documents/users/euZNNwshi6C1GsDW3ONJ, null)
E/flutter (21125): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter (21125): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter (21125): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21125): #2      MethodChannelDocumentReference.updateData (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:41:43)
E/flutter (21125): #3      DocumentReference.updateData (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:60:10)
E/flutter (21125): #4      ListChatScreenState.registerNotification.<anonymous closure> (package:jobly10/chat_implementation/ListChat_screen.dart:73:12)
E/flutter (21125): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (21125): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (21125): #7      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
E/flutter (21125): #8      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
E/flutter (21125): #9      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
E/flutter (21125): #10     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
E/flutter (21125): #11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
E/flutter (21125): #12     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
E/flutter (21125): #13     FirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart)
E/flutter (21125): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21125): #14     ListChatScreenState.registerNotification (package:jobly10/chat_implementation/ListChat_screen.dart:68:23)
E/flutter (21125): #15     ListChatScreenState.initState (package:jobly10/chat_implementation/ListChat_screen.dart:47:5)
E/flutter (21125): #16     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:58)
E/flutter (21125): #17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (21125): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (21125): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (21125): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (21125): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (21125): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (21125): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5445:14)
E/flutter (21125): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (21125): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (21125): #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
E/flutter (21125): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter (21125): #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
E/flutter (21125): #29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (21125): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (21125): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (21125): #32     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
E/flutter (21125): #33     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter (21125): #34     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
E/flutter (21125): #35     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
E/flutter (21125): #36     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4617:11)
E/flutter (21125): #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
E/flutter (21125): #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
E/flutter (21125): #39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
E/flutter (21125): #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
E/flutter (21125): #41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
E/flutter (21125): #42     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.d
```

[image]

**This is my database in firebase**

Comment: The error is simply telling you that you tried to update a document that does exist with the path "users/euZNNwshi6C1GsDW3ONJ".  I think you will have to trust that's true.

Comment: How would you resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't know.  What do you expect to happen? The code here isn't even showing the call to updateData.

Comment: In your first answer did you mean document that exist or it does not exist?

Comment: Does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the field you want to update is not found, so you have to first create the field in firebase the try to use update query to update your field.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30170814)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem (No document to update) and (eventually) discovered that my document id field had acquired a blank space at the *beginning* of the data field.  This made it very hard to recognize, as it looked like the field data was correct, and matching the record (to update).
The record with the bad data was added during development.  I hadn't followed the course instructions to delete all records before continuing, which left some bad records in the database.  Lesson learned!